# React Router v4: Cant load page on GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Locally I can browse to /buttons just fine I can even refresh it and its fine too, but when I upload the build directory to github pages I can't access /buttons and instead I get the GitHub 404 page, not my own 'notfound' page.

If I make a link from the home page to /buttons, then buttons will load, but browsing there directly it does not load.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Context } from "./components/context";
import { Layout } from "./components/layout";
import { Home } from './routes/home';
import { Buttons } from './routes/buttons';
import { NotFound } from './routes/notfound';

const Router: React.FC = () => {

  const [global, setGlobal] = useState({
    language: localStorage.getItem("language") || 'en',
    apiUrl: 'https://api.domain.com/api',
    loggedIn: localStorage.getItem("jwt") ? true : false,
    redirectUrl: '',
    modal: false,
    modalState: '',
  });

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ global, setGlobal }}>
      <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Route render = {({ location }) => (
          <Layout location = { location }>
            <Switch location = { location }>
              <Route exact path = '/' component = { Home } />
              <Route exact path = '/buttons/' component = { Buttons } />
              <Route component = { NotFound }/>
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        )} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
export { Router };
```

In package.json I do have the homepage defined as:

`"homepage": "https://myName.github.io/myRepo",`

Comment: Have you tried removing the basename attribute?

Comment: Yes if I remove it then the default route / shows the NotFound route and /buttons is still not accessible

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per deployment docs at https://create-react-app.dev/, for GH pages:

> GitHub Pages doesn’t support routers that use the HTML5 `pushState` history API under the hood (for example, React Router using `browserHistory`). This is because when there is a fresh page load for a url like `http://user.github.io/todomvc/todos/42`, where `/todos/42` is a frontend route, the GitHub Pages server returns 404 because it knows nothing of `/todos/42`.

If you want to add a router to a project hosted on GitHub Pages, here are a couple of solutions:

- You could switch from using HTML5 history API to routing with hashes. If you use React Router, you can switch to hashHistory for this effect, but the URL will be longer and more verbose (for example, http://user.github.io/todomvc/#/todos/42?_k=yknaj) [Read more](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) about different history implementations of react-router.

Change your routing from:

```js
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Route render = {({ location }) => (
         <Layout location = { location }>
             <Switch location = { location }>
                <Route exact path = '/' component = { Home } />
                <Route exact path = '/buttons/' component = { Buttons } />
                <Route component = { NotFound }/>
              </Switch>
           </Layout>
       )} />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

To:

```js
import { HashRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

...


    <HashRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Route render = {({ location }) => (
         <Layout location = { location }>
             <Switch location = { location }>
                <Route exact path = '/' component = { Home } />
                <Route exact path = '/buttons/' component = { Buttons } />
                <Route component = { NotFound }/>
              </Switch>
           </Layout>
       )} />
    </HashRouter>
...
```

- Alternatively, you can use a trick to teach GitHub Pages to handle 404 by redirecting to your `index.html` page with a special redirect parameter. You would need to add a `404.html` file with the redirection code to the build folder before deploying your project, and you’ll need to add code handling the redirect parameter to `index.html`. You can find a detailed explanation of this technique in [this guide](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages).

Comment: Changing BroswerRouter to HashRouter worked for me. Thanks!