# Deploying react app to github pages is publishing a blank page

Tags: reactjs, github

I created a personal website on my local machine, but I am now having trouble deploying to publish it to github pages.

website repository: https://github.com/vkodangattil/website

When I visit the https://vkodangattil.github.io/website/ all I get is a blank page, even though I know that this app runs fine on localhost. Not sure what to do, I believe I added the correct lines to the package.json file, but I could be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You are having identical paths for all routes, so your routing will only pick the first matched one.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
          <Route path='/' exact component=
          {Home} />
          <Route path='/' exact component=
          {AboutMe} />
          <Route path='/' exact component=
          {Resume} />
          <Route path='/' exact component=
          {Contact} />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

It's because the GitHub page picked homepage URL as your root path but when it loaded with /website path. It can not find any matching URL result in a blank page even though the HTML is loaded.

To adapt that baseUrl you will need to add a `basename` to your BrowserRouter.

**Your final changes should be:**

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import Resume from './components/pages/Resume';
import AboutMe from './components/pages/AboutMe';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter basename="/website">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about-me" component={AboutMe} />
          <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I changed the homepage and redeployed, but am I still getting that same blank page

Comment: Hey, I updated my reply. Why are use using HashRouter? This will lead to an extra `#` at the end of your URL, which is not matched your deploy gh page.
Tell me if it's still not working for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I changed to HashRouter because I saw a couple of answers that said BrowserRouter doesn't work with GitHub pages. I made the changes you suggested, however I'm still getting a blank page

Comment: Hey, Sorry for getting your head around, I updated the answer. The key is to keep the homepage in package.json as: `https://vkodangattil.github.io/website` then put an extra `basename="/website"` to your `BrowserRouter`, so gh page would sync your root path with the baseUrl from the defined `homepage`.

Comment: One more note is that if you try to directly access `https://github.com/vkodangattil/website/about-me` it won't work, because gh-page doesn't find an index.html file in that file URL. But still, you can access these pages from the Client Side of your Link component.

Comment: Further readings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228017/react-router-v4-cant-load-page-on-github-pages

Comment: The homepage and basename stuff worked, thank you so much! As for the router stuff, I actually went back to how it was originally with the path being "/" for every route and it deployed correctly. I wanted the components of the routes to display below each other, and when you click on the route, the page scrolls to the component. Again thank you so much, I spent so much time on this!

Comment: No problems, mate! I also learned something today.