# Why does my GitHub page only show the homepage for my react app and not the other pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So Im trying to deploy my weather app to GitHub Pages and I have installed gh pages as well as added the web link to homepages in my package.json file. But when I go on the live site, it only shows the homepage and not the other "subpages" I have. If I click on the cities on top to get to that page, it shows a 404 error. What should I do??

This is the link I have in package.json:
"homepage": "https://mw3981.github.io/Weather_App/"

[image]

Comment: react router takes the / of `<Route path="/">`  to be the first subpage after the domain, but github adds the repository name as the subpage, which react router takes as `< Route path="/reponame"/>`. I don't get this error because I use vercel for deployment of my react apps (you can use netlify as well but make sure to mention that it is a single page application in the `netlify.toml` file)

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that you have a disconnect between what the router is expecting and how Github pages serves pages from within a repo.

Github always wants to have "/Weather_App/" at the start of the path.
(so the homepage is "https://mw3981.github.io/Weather_App/")

The router in react isn't expecting this, so when it tries to serve a subpage it's trying to go to "https://mw3981.github.io/subpage" instead of what github is expecting: "https://mw3981.github.io/Weather_App/subpage"

Try adding/using `basename` the prop mentioned [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter).

Also, there may be some compatibility issues between Github Pages and how the router is doing page changes via `pushState`. That's discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58280415/1608016).