# React-Router issue when deployed to Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I'm having a little bit of trouble deploying a multipage React App (using React-Router V.6) on Github Pages. On my actual deployment build ([here](https://mramirez0610.github.io/portfolio/)), whenever I go to a route (such as about or resume) and refresh, I get a 404. I assume this is due to Client-Side Rendering, along with GH Pages only knowing the base url "/portfolio", and not knowing "/portfolio/about".

I'm still learning the ropes of React-Router, so I've been searching for crazy for a solution, but have had no luck. I've searched through these solutions :

[React Router v4: Cant load page on GitHub pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228017/react-router-v4-cant-load-page-on-github-pages)

https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages

and neither have seemed to work for me.

**Boiling my question down to the simplest terms, I'm wondering what the easiest way to fix this is.**

I've tried switching my BrowserRouter to HashRouter, but that didn't work. I attempted to add a 404.html file along with a redirect script in my Index.html, but that didn't work either. I'm not looking for anything too robust, since this is just a portfolio site hosted on GH Pages, but I do want to keep the url's looking clean if possible.

Again, here is my [deployment build](https://mramirez0610.github.io/portfolio/), along with [source code](https://github.com/mramirez0610/portfolio)

Apologies if this question is too long! This is my first StackOverflow question. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I believe that you are already going in the right direction**

Reference to [this repo](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages), copy the last script from [here](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L21) and add the 404.html file, then it will be fine.

Comment: tried and retried the tutorial 6 times before you left this comment, but on the 7th, it worked. thank you so much, i would've given up on this solution if it wasn't for you !!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I just tried to point out where you were likely to miss.