# page not found - react/vite app not routing correctly on github pages

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, github-pages, vite

I deployed my app to `gh-pages` and the root works, but whenever I reroute or try and add to the root, I get a page not found error. Locally it works.

I've seen people suggest changing from `<BrowserRouter>` to `<HashRouter>` but that didn't help. I've also seen, and even used, a solution for `create-react-app` or `webpack` where you add some code to the `index.html` file in the `public` directory as well as a `404.html` but the issue is `vite` has a different file structure.

Where would I put them in a `vite` application where there's nothing in the `public` directory. It does have a `dist` folder with an `index.html` but I'm not sure if that's the one.

Not sure what code I would need to show, but here's my `main.jsx` and `App.jsx` files:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/example" element={<Example />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Again, locally this works, and when deploying to `gh-pages` the root or home page work, but no extended routes. Like I said, I had a similar issue with `webpack` but the solution I got there didn't work since `vite` has different file structure so I was unsure how to add the correct files.

EDIT: I've also seen a github [issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9201) where a user had a similar issue and the solution was to define routes in the `vite.config.js` but again the difference there is that user had multiple `index.html` files for each component/route. I just have the standard `<BrowserRouter>` situation wrapping my routes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router issue when deployed to Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290365/react-router-issue-when-deployed-to-github-pages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding a `404.html` in the public folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Page Not Found</title>
    <script>
      sessionStorage.redirect = location.href;
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/'" />
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

This JS in the root's `index.html` just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
    <script>
      (() => {
        const redirect = sessionStorage.redirect;
        delete sessionStorage.redirect;
        if (redirect && redirect !== location.href) {
          history.replaceState(null, null, redirect);
        }
      })();
    </script>
```

And lastly reconfiguring the `vite.config.js` file:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
        404: resolve(__dirname, "public/404.html"),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: resolve showing deprecated when doing the above - no docs anywhere for what to replace it with for vite build.... how to get update?

Answer (score 1):

The main point here is to understand how GH pages serve static files. If there is not a file matched to a given URL, it automatically serves `404.html`. So we just need to have `404.html`, which has the same content as the `index.html` that we get from vite build.

**Therefore, all you need to to is to copy `index.html` to `404.html` inside `dist` directory.**

I'm not sure how you manage GH page publish.

- If you use Github Actions, please add a custom step to copy `index.html` to `404.html`.

  ```
  cp ./dist/index.html ./dist/404.html
  ```
- If you use `gh-pages` branch, I think you should copy `index.html` to `404.html` before you push your changes to the branch.

I have created a public repo, which you can take a look for a reference.
https://github.com/richard929/vite-gh-pages-example

I used react-router v6, and github actions for GH pages publish. I hope you already know about `base` configuration of `vite`, when deploying Vite app to static website.

Comment: When deploying `gh-pages` it runs `npm run build` which creates a new dist folder. How can I keep this file in the folder during production

Comment: I think it depends on the way deploying to production. If you use pipelines, you can always extend it to add custom step. If you do this manually, then no trouble, I suppose.